# optionから受け取った選択しをselectのvalue変数へ

Tags: perl

お世話になってます。初心者ですがなにとぞよろしくお願いします。

formの中に本人確認実施フラグを作りたいですが、optionから受け取ったtrueまたfalseはselectのvalue変数gui->{check_flag} へ設置したいです。以下のようなコードでどのように連携すればいいのかわかりません。詳しい方は教えて頂ければ助かります。

**該当部分のソースコード**

```
<select name="check_flag" value="<%= gui->{check_flag} %>">
<option value="true" >true</option>
<option value="false" selected >false</option>
</select>
```

**画面表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3/6追加：
int32_tさんのおしゃる通り、selectタグにvalue属性がありません。コードは以下のように改造しました。

```
<select class="form-control" name="check_flag" id="check_flag">
　　<option value="false" <%= gui->{check_flag} eq "false" ? 'selected' : '' %>>実施しない</option>
　　<option value="true" <%= gui->{check_flag} eq "true" ? 'selected' : '' %>>実施する</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ちなみに、テキストに直接入力する場合は、<input type="text" placeholder="" name="check_flag" value="<%= gui-->{check_flag} %>"> でうまくできましたけど、選択式で実現したいです。

Comment: 追加の情報もなるべく本文に直接追記してください。 / formと言っても`gui->`としているのが気になります、HTMLのフォームなのか、GUIアプリ？のフォームなのかが分かるようにもう少し詳しく書いてもらうと回答が付きやすいと思います (データを受け取る側のPerlの記述が無いですよね？)。

Comment: 申し訳誤ございません。 cubick様、ご整理して頂き、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 時間を経て、再度確認しましたところで、上記のコードでうまくいきました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: select要素にvalue属性は無いので、何をしたいのか疑問です。https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element:concept-element-attributes